# Shared_ptr doubly linkedlist memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, shared-ptr, doubly-linked-list

I am getting some memory leak although using smart_ptr.

```
class linkedlist{
public:
    linkedlist(){}
 private:
    struct node{
        shared_ptr<node> prev{nullptr};
        shared_ptr<node> next{nullptr};
        int data;
    };
    shared_ptr<node> head{nullptr};
    shared_ptr<node> tail{nullptr};
 };
```

Comment: interesting, perhaps use valgrind to find the leak?

Comment: @IronMan Checked the memory using valgrind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because this forms a cycle, which can't be dealt with by shared ptr.

For example, with two nodes `a` and `b` in your list:

```cpp
{
    linkedlist l;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<node> a{new node};
        std::shared_ptr<node> b{new node};
        // a count: 1, b count: 1
        a.next = b;
        b.prev = a;
        // a count: 2, b count: 2
        l.head = a;
        l.tail = b;
        // a count: 3, b count: 3
    }
    // a count: 2, b count: 2  (local variables destructed)
}
// a count: 1, b count: 1 (l, l.head and l.tail destructed)
// count != 0, so not deleted and memleak
```

To fix this, have `node.prev` and `linkedlist.tail` be a `std::weak_ptr` to prevent nodes indirectly holding a strong reference to themselves through `node.prev.next` or `node.next.prev`

Comment: Why would you use a "weak" "smart pointer" instead of a plain pointer?

Answer (score 0):

here is the working code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class linkedlist{
public:
    linkedlist(){}
    void inserthead(int value){
        shared_ptr<node> temp=make_shared<node>(value);
        if(head==nullptr){
            head=temp;
            tail=head;
        }else{
            head->prev=temp;
            temp->next=head;
            head=temp;
        }
    }
    void inserttail(int value){
        shared_ptr<node> temp=make_shared<node>(value);
        if(head==nullptr){
            head=temp;
            tail=head;
        }else{
            temp->prev=tail;
            auto ptr=tail.lock();
            ptr->next=temp;
            tail=temp;
        }

    }
    void print(){
        shared_ptr<node> temp=head;
        while (temp!=nullptr)
        {
            cout<<temp->data<<endl;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
private:
    struct node{
        node(int value):data(value){
        }
        weak_ptr<node> prev;
        shared_ptr<node> next{nullptr};
        int data;
    };
    shared_ptr<node> head{nullptr};
    weak_ptr<node> tail;
};
```